# Toggle between active and inactive tabs

Tags: javascript

I have a list which I would like to toggle between active and remove the active class if another was clicked. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
              <li rel="tab-1" class="active">Tab One</li>
              <li rel="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
              <li rel="tab-3">Tab 3</li>
            </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs>li');
  var otherTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs>li.active");
  
  tabs.forEach((tab) => {
    tab.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      otherTabs.forEach((otherTab) => {
      otherTab.classList.remove('active');
  });
    tab.classList.add('active');
  });
  });
  
})();
```

CSS

```
.active {
background: red;
}
```

Basically, when a tab is clicked, the background will be red and all other tabs have the active class removed if they have that class and then the background is gone from them. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to add the active class in the clicked tab only. Currently you are adding it to all non active lists. Just add it to the clicked dom using the passed event `e`

Comment: You could edit this question to make this a runnable snippet.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan are you sure about that?  The indentation is irregular, but I believe the code is correct..

Comment: Yeah I just noticed. The code seems fine. Thanks

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan, yeah, the issue is actually that the selector makes use of `.active`, but was only executed once.

Comment: Ohhh I get it now. Because its dynamically changing so need to fetch the updated items everytime. Yes.... So the below answer does the job

Answer (score 3):

You just need to move your `otherTabs` declaration to be inside of the `click` event. This forces it to check the HTML every time there is a click.

```js
(function() {
  var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs>li');

  tabs.forEach((tab) => {
    tab.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      var otherTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs>li.active");
      otherTabs.forEach((otherTab) => {
        otherTab.classList.remove('active');
      });
      tab.classList.add('active');
    });
  });

})();
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li rel="tab-1" class="active">Tab One</li>
  <li rel="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
  <li rel="tab-3">Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't have any effect on the code, but it might also be worth changing the variable name to something like `activeTabs`, since `otherTabs` could contain the clicked tab, nothing, or any combination of other tabs as long as they have the active class.

Answer (score 0):

simply use `classList.toggle('active', [boolean]) )`
to remove or add your class.
Note: the code is more readable with event delegation

```js
(function()
  {
  const tabsParent = document.querySelector('ul.tabs')
    ,   All_tabs   = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tabs>li')
    ;
  tabsParent.onclick = ({target}) =>
    {
    if (!target.matches('ul.tabs>li')) return
    
    All_tabs.forEach(tb=>tb.classList.toggle('active', tb===target) )
    }
  })();
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
  }
ul.tabs>li {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li rel="tab-1" class="active">Tab One</li>
  <li rel="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
  <li rel="tab-3">Tab 3</li>
</ul>
```